# Hotmail - automatically encode the URL

Tags: php, hotmail

I'm developing an application with PHP that sends emails to customers. The body of the email contains a URL hyperlink back to our site kind of like this:

http://myserver/myfolder/test.cfm?id=una-bottiglia-di-vino-©-®

The above url contatins copyright and registered symbols

In Yahoo, GMail, Outlook, etc. the link displayed as I sent. However Hotmail displays the href url as encoded

http://myserver/myfolder/test.cfm?id=una-bottiglia-di-vino-%a9-%ae

Comment: `©-®`are not valid characters in a URL. They should be URLencoded. What is your question?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: http://myserver/myfolder/test.cfm?id=una-bottiglia-di-vino-©-® this link is working fine for me, but hotmail encode that link by default, so the link displayed in the hotmail is not working for me. I need hotmail to display the link without encoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mail you just do urlencode($myUrl);

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php